# External hdmi connected display doesn't show mouse pointer

Tags: system

Elementary OS detects OK the hdmi display (digital TV) connected to my laptop port, but when I select it to use, everything displays except the mouse pointer. So, I can't access any program. Your help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does the mouse pointer *work* on that display? i.e. if you hover somewhere can you see the effects? Open this page: https://jsfiddle.net/zj3zcffs/ and hover over the bottom right box. It should turn yellow.

Comment: Tim:
Thanks for answering. When I'm using the external display the only thing that shows is the background image of my laptop. I can't open a browser window since there is no mouse pointer to hover over.

Comment: Little correction to above: "... the only thing that shows is the background image and the app launcher at the bottom of my laptop." Sorry.

Comment: Can you drag a window from your internal display?

Comment: Tim: Yes! I can drag any window from the laptop display to the external display and the mouse follows. Now, will there be an option that, when I choose the external display all the stuff moves to the external display? Tried mirroring, but it didn't do it. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Tim: Additional problem. I can drag the window to the external display, but the audio doesn't go with it. So, I can see videos but the audio stays in the laptop..